# Deserializing a simple list in a response

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am doing something like this:

```
RestResponse<OTContentReply> response = (RestResponse<OTContentReply>)client.Execute<OTContentReply>(request);
```

where OTContentReplay is a very simple class containing 4 strings like so:

```
public class OTContentReply
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string embed { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

The response contains a number of OTContentReply nodes and my code above does place the first node in an instance of OTConentReply. (Great!)

What I want to do now is get all of the content nodes into an array or list. I tried this:

```
RestResponse<List<OTContentReply>> response = (RestResponse<List<OTContentReply>>)client.Execute<List<OTContentReply>>(request);
```

but get the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'RestSharp.RestResponse<System.Collections.Generic.List<Algoa.OpenTouchCtrl.OTContentReply>>' to 'RestSharp.RestResponse'
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: what is the response format xml or json ?